# How to save information of authorized logon user

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, formsauthenticationticket

Im using ASP.NET web application and FormsAuthenticationTicket.
In the FormsAuthenticationTicket i save the userName but i need the ID of the user too.
I have tried to save the ID in Session but its not always works.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, t.FullName,      DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), CheckBox1.Checked, t.Credential, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);
```

is there a way to save the ID too in better way?

Comment: Are you using standard asp.net forms auth?

Comment: im pretty sure that is the standard

Comment: Check out the Forms authentication example here at msdn: 
[Forms authentication example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thanks, but in the ticket object i saved name= userName userData = credential. i need to save in some way the ID.